# JobConf from TaskAttemptContext

Tags: java, hadoop, amazon-web-services

I am trying to get hold of `JobConf` inside a custom `TextInputFormat` class.

```
public RecordReader<LongWritable,Text> createRecordReader(InputSplit split, TaskAttemptContext context) {
 return new XmlInputFormat(split, ...jobconf...);
}
```

How would I do that?

Hadoop 0.20 API please (Amazon EMR requirement)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TaskAttemptContext has a getJobConf method which returns the JobConf:

- `org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptContext.getJobConf()`